# What are the political reasons behind the Western media highlighting the HIMARS vehicles over the MLRS vehicles that Ukraine has recently received?

Tags: ukraine, military, media

Ukraine has received 20 [HIMARS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M142_HIMARS#Current_operators) vehicles and "more than 10" [MLRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M270_Multiple_Launch_Rocket_System#Current_operators). A HIMARS has six rounds, which is half of the twelve rounds of an MLRS, but it is on a wheeled chassis instead of a tracked one. However, in Western news reports, it is HIMARS that is more often mentioned by name. Is there a political reason behind this?

1. Could it be that Ukraine is more interested in highlighting the ongoing American aid?
2. Could it be that the larger MLRS is less suitable for Ukrainian conditions, so the Western media does not want to draw attention to it?
3. Is it a communications or PR issue, such as the news reports being based on press releases from the weapon manufacturer or the country that manufactures it?
4. Are there any other less obvious political reasons?

Comment: Is the question why the press talks about HIMARS but not MLRS?

Comment: The big deal about HIMARS is its 70+ km range provides Ukraine with the ability to attack the Russian rear. However, this is due to the GMLRS missile which both [MLRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M142_HIMARS#GMLRS) and [HIMARS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M270_Multiple_Launch_Rocket_System#GMLRS) can use. They probably should be reporting on the GMLRS missile rather than the launcher vehicles.

Comment: @Schwern, the question is if the Ukrainian press releases and statements talk about both and the press 'simplifies' it, or if the press releases just talk about HIMARS and the press reports that. And also, if anybody knows, about the actual use.

Comment: To the layman, HIMARS vs MLRS is a distinction without a difference. HIMARS has a catchy name, it arrived first, and more of them arrived. The actual use of the weapons is largely kept secret due to their high value. Official statements on actual use tend to be vague or ambiguous. You would need to clarify what you want to know about actual use to get more information on that. There are a lot of videos posted unofficially to social media platforms showing rockets launching from both systems, but multiple rockets don't launch concurrently, they launch one at a time per vehicle.

Comment: This seems more suited for a hardcore military Q&A site than for this forum.  How is this about politics?  If we were talking about up-missiling to ATACMS or whatever the long ranges ones are called, yes, there would be a political dimension.  This however is a nomenclature Q within the same general family of weapons.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica, Ukraine has been alternately prodding and praising various countries in order to get more arms. (Understandable, from their side.) I wondered if the praise for US rather than European gifts is Ukrainian policy or press laziness.

Comment: This would make it on-topic, but both are US are they not?  Or you could ask from whom the MRLS/HIMARS came from (the UK gave 3, I think, other Euros may have chipped in to), which is a different question.  As far as praising European gifts there is just less to praise - cough, Germany, cough, France, cough.  Though sometimes that's because the volume just isn't there to give.  Honorable mentions to UK, Poland, Lithuania et all however.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica, actually Germany gave more MLRS than the Brits. Which is just my point re messaging. *Especially* if one counts one MLRS as two HIMARS, and not one.

Answer (score 4):

Ukraine will not tell which launcher has been used, this is a military secret. Russia maybe would but they only see the rocket. Hence there is not much information available for the press about the actual usage of MLRS and HIMARS on the battlefield, and I do not really see many such articles in the independent press. When they write generally about these weapons, seems mentioning both, see [this The New York Times article](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/09/09/us/ukraine-weapons-rockets.html?unlocked_article_code=3jaelhvpWNZueOu0Cyl2Tfj0093uDmozguTv1Y5s8TJVxSgHwpkW1qTMPeUzQ4ZJ5a_AT_8b1-sFemf_IOJPMM2xukKOjui4078nBEw42NtwDbM4AtPDtpZZFC30SCtgD-BgbqmW3So6LZdw85hwiyuXi9UGjYwpNve0X6qvrorqdi1W6gmCo5qp1ssCkq1sWZikgW0fwV0X33xByHrsaV1iiJxX76H6hRzNCX0JUwBRNhTFOyMklq1Cxh2gRqlNImb6BKIkFfQqnTiQJypCEVnCclJ9n7q0QVBEagrEpAiynjctMKYNyQDBVyr6NWMCSU8NR7AHGkzAPf9PlA&smid=share-url). Some articles just about HIMARS, they success only appeared before MLRS have been delivered.

HIMARS were first, have been discussed for longer and made easier observable changes in the battlefield. Hence they are more notable for this war. This makes them more suitable for various fakes [like this](https://www.stopfake.org/ru/fejk-vsu-obstrelyali-herson-iz-himars-s-tselyu-obvinit-v-etom-rossijskih-voennyh/) and general propaganda push. I think it is Russian press that writes about HIMARS more than about MLRS.

Answer (score 3):

HIMARS was delivered *first* in a single coordinated *package*, from the *USA* after a period in which there had been *debate* about the wisdom of providing such weaponry.  It has a pronounceable *acronym*.

MLRS was delivered later, in several small deals, from German, France and the UK, after the debate about HIMARS had finished. That makes it less interesting.

The distinction is rather irrelevant, they both blow things up and kill people in nasty ways, so as a non-expert in military logistics, I'm not too bothered if a journalist makes a mistake and refers to a tracked M270 as a wheeled M142.

I've no idea which system is better suited to Ukrainian conditions. Probably both are fine.